# How to store the result when iterating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a Rails newbie so I don't have a clear idea on how to approach this problem.

I have an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` object stored in `@electives`. Specifically, I have
`@electives = @degree.electives`

`Degree` and `Elective` are models with tables `degrees` and `electives`. I have defined a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between `Degree` and `Elective` models.

Additionally, I also have a `Course` model with a corresponding `courses` table. I have also defined another `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between `Course` and `Elective` models.

In addition to the above listed tables, I also have `degrees_electives` and `courses_electives` join tables.

Now, I want to display on a page, a **list** of Electives in a Degree, and all the Courses associated to an Elective. So, I want something like:

```
- Software Engineering Elective A
    - COMP SCI 3008 Computer Networks & Applications
    - COMP SCI 1234 Object Oriented Programming
    - COMP SCI 4567 Algorithm Design & Data Structure Analysis

- Software Engineering Elective B
    - MATHS 1012 Mathematics IA
    - CIVIL 2000 Civil Engineering Introduction

- Software Engineering Elective C
    - COMP SCI 1012 Introduction to Programming
```

I am able to display the list:

```
- Software Engineering Elective A
- Software Engineering Elective B
- Software Engineering Elective C
```

**But I don't know how to display the sub-list.**

Currently, I have in my **controller**:

```
@degree = @student.degrees.first
@electives = @degree.electives
```

`@degree` contains a `Degree` object.

And, my **view** contains:

```
<ul>
<% @electives.each do |elective| %>
  <li>
    <%= elective.name %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

The webpage looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the webpage]

I would like help with displaying the sub-list.

What I am stuck at is, how should I store the list and make it available to the view, when I call `.courses` on each element of `@electives`. For example, I could do:

```
@electives.each do |elective|
  @courses = elective.courses
end
```

But then, `@courses` will contain courses that correspond with the last element of `@electives`, if and when I use `@courses` in the view.

Is there like a vector data structure available in Ruby that I can push values to? I don't know how to do this. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over courses that are associated with an elective in the same way as you already iterate over the courses with the only difference to do it nested within the other iteration:

```
<ul>
  <% @electives.each do |elective| %>
    <li><%= elective.name %>
      <ul>
        <% elective.courses.each do |course| %>
          <li><%= course.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

To avoid a [N + 1 queries problem](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) I suggest eager loading all courses that are associated with the electives in one query by changing your controller to:

```
@degree = @student.degrees.first
@electives = @degree.electives.includes(:courses)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need variable

```rb
<ul>
<% @electives.each do |elective| %>
    <li>
       <%= elective.name %>
       <ul>
          <% @elective.courses.each do |course|%>
            <li>
            <%= course.name %>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

In controller you better include elective with course to have it initialized, to not have n*m calls to database

```rb
@electives = Elective.includes(:courses)
```

Comment: OP has `@electives` as degree electives, not all electives

Comment: Add where to this, and you’re good to go

Comment: You don't need add `where`, just `@degree.electives.includes(:courses)`